# Converter not found? XamlParseException: Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key StringTruncator

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, converters

I've included the `StringTruncator` converter in my `App.Resources`

```
xmlns:app="clr-namespace:Tabbed_Browser">

<!--Application Resources-->
<Application.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>
        <app:StringTruncator x:Key="StringTruncator" />
        <app:StringTruncatorFav x:Key="StringTruncatorFav" />        
        <app:AppInfo x:Key="AppInfo" />
        <app:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" /       
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

Then in the UserControl XML I refer to it via this code

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" x:Name="txtPageTitle" 
            Text="{Binding BrowserViewModel.PageTitle, Converter={StaticResource StringTruncator}}" 
            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"    
            VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

The `StringTruncator` is a simple converter that append `...` if the string exceed certain length.

```
namespace Tabbed_Browser
{
public class StringTruncator : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return ""; 

        string str = value.ToString();
        int maxChars = 44;
        return str.Length <= maxChars ? str : str.Substring(0, maxChars) + "...";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

But then I run the project I get the following. Removing the `StringTruncator` converter in the code eliminate the error but I need to use the converter. What am I missing?

```
{System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:
 Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key StringTruncator [Line: 15 Position: 22]
  at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
  at Tabbed_Browser.User_Controls.UCAddressBar.InitializeComponent()
  at Tabbed_Browser.User_Controls.UCAddressBar..ctor()}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **DynamicResource** instead, this way it will be applied at runtime. Or you can add resources to the Usercontrol.Resources itself. Or you can do like that also, but you must add namespace to UserControl also:

```
  Text="{Binding BrowserViewModel.PageTitle, Converter={app:StringTruncator}}"
```